# Incorporate rotation into regular polygon algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, polygon

**I wrote this algorithm to draw a regular polygon**:

```
var sides = 6,
    radius = 50;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y - radius);
for(n = 1; n <= sides; n++)
    ctx.lineTo(
        x + (radius * Math.sin(n * 2 * Math.PI / sides)), 
        y + (-1 * radius * Math.cos(n * 2 * Math.PI / sides))
    );
ctx.stroke();
```

It works wonderfully, but I need to incorporate a way to rotate the polygon, **without** using the  `ctx.rotate()` function.

**Thanks for your help.** *If you down vote, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to generate a regular polygon with the first vertex at zero-angle-right-of-center:

[image]

The code uses trigonometry to rotate the polygon instead of `context.rotate`.

```
function regularPolygon(cx,cy,sides,radius,radianRotation){
    var deltaAngle=Math.PI*2/sides;
    var x=function(rAngle){return(cx+radius*Math.cos(rAngle-radianRotation));}
    var y=function(rAngle){return(cy+radius*Math.sin(rAngle-radianRotation));}
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x(0),y(0));
    for(n = 1; n <= sides; n++){
        var angle=deltaAngle*n;
        ctx.lineTo(x(angle),y(angle));
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```